# What triggers these Django urls tag?

Tags: django

Programmers in the house,

I want to know what triggers both of these types of django urls

{%  url '$name' %}

{% url 'appname:$name' %}

is there a setting that helps you to choose either of them?

Answer (score 0):

The first one is regular URL while the second use URL namespaces.

URL namespaces allow you to uniquely reverse named URL patterns even if different applications use the same URL names. It’s a good practice.

For example you can have a url like that : {% url 'blog:index' %} and {% url 'shopping:index' %}

See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces)